# Heroku throws rollback errors while creating book record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently building a application where I have a Book Model.
It works locally without any problems at all. I deployed it to Heroku and ran `rake db:migrate` and tried to create a book

I got following ROLLBACK error.

```
2018-03-29T07:29:59.748305+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.748238 #4] DEBUG -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec]   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-03-29T07:29:59.750826+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.750763 #4] DEBUG -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec]    (0.8ms)  BEGIN
2018-03-29T07:29:59.763631+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.763526 #4] DEBUG -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec]    (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
2018-03-29T07:29:59.764270+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.764208 #4]  INFO -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec]   Rendering books/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-03-29T07:29:59.770061+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.769996 #4]  INFO -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec]   Rendered books/_form.html.erb (5.5ms)
2018-03-29T07:29:59.770167+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.770113 #4]  INFO -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec]   Rendered books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.8ms)
2018-03-29T07:29:59.771544+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.771486 #4]  INFO -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec]   Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.7ms)
2018-03-29T07:29:59.771904+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.771828 #4]  INFO -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec]   Rendered layouts/_alerts.html.erb (0.2ms)
2018-03-29T07:29:59.772181+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-29T07:29:59.772125 #4]  INFO -- : [feda9269-2f19-4916-a87f-bc179fd52bec] Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

Books Controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :book_owner, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]
    def index
        @books = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @book = current_user.books.build
        @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    end

    def create
        @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)
        @book.category_id = params[:category_id]
        if @book.save
            redirect_to books_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    end

    def update
        @book.category_id = params[:category_id]
        if @book.update(book_params)
            redirect_to book_path(@book)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @book.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end


    private

    def book_params
        params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, :author, :category_id)
    end

    def find_book
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    def book_owner
        unless current_user.id == @book.user_id
            flash[:notice] = "You are not allowed to do that!"
            redirect_to @book
        end
    end

end
```

Book Model

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
end
```

Book new view

```
<%= simple_form_for @book, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :category_id, collection: @categories, prompt: "Select a category" %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
  <%= f.input :author %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn-outline-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Update:

```
Started POST "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-29 11:13:22 +0200
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UYKPhHA99zg5TMMwgKGk+h2OPPaCQkpkjohPRnRNQHlJB1eQF4Ooro4Tvx9VDSr3U6/H4AGoThu8jzkrwyMbUB==", "book"=>{"category_id"=>"", "title"=>"tesas", "author"=>"asdasd", "description"=>"asdasd"}, "commit"=>"Create Book"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering books/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered books/_form.html.erb (10.0ms)
  Rendered books/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_alerts.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 46.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Category_id is nil because i don't have them set yet on my second laptop because i can't get a Category.connection (Category.create(name: "SOMECATEGORY") using this to create a Category but it won't work without Category.connection)
On my heroku application i was able to do Category.connection and Category.create .. - but even after that it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help in advance as always!

Comment: can you please share some more information like your book model and controller part?

Comment: Excuse me, i dont know what happend to my Post here, it should've been included already.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the record is invalid. The reason is you are not properly assigning the `category_id`.

You need to change `params[:category_id]` to `book_params[:category_id]`

params[:category_id] will give you `nil` and the validation check will fail.

```
def create
  @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)
  @book.category_id = book_params[:category_id]
  if @book.save
    redirect_to books_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

You need to make the same changes for `update` action as well

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work.

I wonder how its working without ur suggestion on my local machine..
I just tried to run my application on my other Laptop, same result as on heroku. rollback... I can't even get a Book.connection / Category.connection because it says its uninitialized constant Book / Category

Comment: can you please post

Comment: As per your params the solution i suggested should solve the problem

Comment: Also check if you are getting the category_id on heroku as well

Comment: Or you can try creating the same record on console

Comment: I do get the category_id on heroku as well. 

But how come that i don't get any of the errors on my local machine I ? I don't have the params like above (book_params) - but it works?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I think i found my error : my user_id was nil when creating via web - i created the same record on console and passed the parameter user_id - voila, works. My user_id parameter somehow don't pass on the heroku rails server but it does on the local machine. No code lines were changed.

How is this even possible?